# javascript append method anchor link is not working in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

Anchor link is not working with append method i also use link data-ajax="false" please let me know?

```
$('#serviceContainer').append('<li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">'+trimText(events.event_title,30)+'</li>'+
'<li data-theme="d" class="li_list">'+'<div data-role="content"><a  data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide" href="detail.htm?eid='+events.event_id+'">Details</a></div></li>').trigger("create");
```

Comment: show a little more code? the explanation is not so clear...

Comment: this is the link not working                                                  <a  data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide" href="detail.htm?eid='+events.event_id+'" style="float:right;color:#333;text-decoration:none;margin-top:-50px;">Details</a>

Comment: Your code is too complicated; you should start by removing things like `style` attributes, and replace them with classes or ids (when appropriate). You might also consider some templating.

Comment: this part will probably not work as expected: `'+events.event_id+'` - you cannot use JavaScript like this, the JS part would not be executed here... or does that link code come from JavaScript, too?

Comment: '+events.event_id+' this is json object and id

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would consider using a template to reduce the complexity of your code and make it far easier to work with. There are many templating solutions out there, even a [jQuery one](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl).

It's fairly straight forward. You start by providing your template within a script tag:

```
<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
        <img src="${img}" />
        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide" href="${href}">
                Details
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</script>
```

Here I've indicated that I would like to provide an image, and an href value for my template when and if I decide to use it.

Within my jQuery code, I can grab this template and name it:

```
var itemtmpl = $( "#itemTemplate" ).template();
```

Lastly, when I'd like to use this I just provide it an object literal that has all of the placeholder values:

```
$.tmpl( itemtmpl , { img: "mainImage.jpg", href: "main.html" } )
    .appendTo( "#mylist" );​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Note how friendly this is compared to your initial approach.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2k2HQ/